# no response when try to build a .pyx file

Tags: python, cython, setuptools

I'm trying to build a `.pyx` file using `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` in terminal. The setup.py file is:

```
from setuptools import Extension, setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy

ext_modules = Extension(
        "xxx",
        ["xxx.pyx"],
        include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()],
        extra_compile_args=["-O3", "-fopenmp"],
        extra_link_args=["-fopenmp"],
    )

setup(
    name='xxx',
    ext_modules=cythonize(ext_modules, annotate=True),
    zip_safe=False,
)
```

I have two conda environment, one is `python 3.9.13` + `cython 0.29.32` + `setuptools 63.4.1` (**env1**), the other is `python 3.11.3` + `cython 3.0.0b3` + `setuptools 67.8.0` (**env2**).

However, the command will only work in **env1**. When I using **env2**, the terminal just printed `running build_ext` and then nothing happened. No error, no warning, and no compilation. I can't figure out what's wrong with **env2**.